# Transition from a UITableViewController to a UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

For aesthetic reasons, I'd like the initial controller of my iPhone app to be a UITableViewController.

But, in response to a row selection, I'd like to display a UITabBarController.

Is this possible? Can one transition from a UITableViewController to a UITabBarController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, anything is possible!

In your case, you want a root controller (a simple UIViewController will do) with the UITableViewController as initial subview. Then when you want, swap it with your UITabBarController using your choice of animation, see the sample "utility" app for an example.